# How to fix emacs shift-up key for text selection in mintty on Cygwin

Tags: emacs, cygwin, emacs24, mintty

I'm giving emacs a go, and running it in mintty / Cygwin on Windows.

I'm running emacs version 24.3.1.

I've found that emacs uses ephemeral mode text selection by default these days, with Shift + arrow keys used for selecting text, like most modern UIs.

However, there is one key binding that isn't working inside mintty: Shift+Up.

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was something wrong in the terminfo settings for xterm, which is what mintty emulates.

I used [esr's `showkey`](http://www.catb.org/esr/showkey/) to dump what the terminal was sending for Shift-Up, Shift-Down:

```
^[ 1 ; 2 A   shift-up
^[ 1 ; 2 B   shift-down
```

I decompiled the terminfo entries for `xterm` (which didn't work properly) and `rxvt` (which did, when run in an rxvt terminal) with `infocmp -L xterm` and `infocmp -L rxvt`, and noticed that the sequences above were mapped for `xterm` to `key_sr` (`kind`) and `key_sf` (`kri`) - [see the definition of those guys here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/terminfo.html). But `rxvt` had no such entries.

So I tweaked the entries:

```
$ infocmp xterm > xterm.ti
```

Applied this change:

```
-       kind=\E[1;2B, kmous=\E[M, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
-       kri=\E[1;2A, mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, meml=\El,
+       kmous=\E[M, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
+       mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, meml=\El,
```

Compiled and installed updated xterm:

```
$ tic xterm.ti
```

This fixed selection with Shift+Up in emacs.